# Как сделать автодеплой при пуше в конкретную ветку в репозитории?

Tags: git, развертывание, gitlab

Допустим есть Gitlab, с репозиторием `test.git`. В нем есть множество веток, и две основные `master` и `qa`. В процессе разработки, разработчики создают свои ветки которые соответствуют задачам, далее все это мержится через мержреквесты в ветку `dev`. Когда нужно выкатить релиз, есть необходимость делать деплой на тестовый сервер из ветки `qa`, и когда тест прошел успешно нужно сделать деплой на продакшн из ветки `master`.

Предположим что тестовый сервер и продакшн-сервер находятся на одной машине. В данный момент, после того как были подмержены все изменения из `dev` в `qa`, после пуша, я иду на сервер и выполняю там команду, что-то вроде этой:

```
git archive --remote=/git-data/repositories/root/test.git qa | tar -x -C /test-server/sites/test/
```

Если протестили и все ок, ветка `qa` мержится в `master`, и я опять иду на сервер, и выполняю такую команду:

```
git archive --remote=/git-data/repositories/root/test.git master | tar -x -C /prod-server/sites/test/
```

Это все напряжно, и хочется автоматизировать этот процесс. Хочется создать какой-нибудь bash-скрипт (например просто вбить в него эту же `git archive` покачто), который будет автоматически запускаться после внесения изменений в ветку `master` или `qa`. Например после пуша в `qa` сработает скрипт `/home/testuser/deplloy-qa.sh`, а после пуша в `master` сработает скрипт `/home/testuser/deplloy-master.sh`. Или же, можно было бы выполнять такие скрипты не автоматически при пуше, а из интерфейса Gitlab'a (что более интереснее, и на мой взгляд удобнее), там есть такие штуки как Builds/Runners - я не знаю можно ли их использоваться для решения моей задачи.

Буду признателен за полезные ответы, хотелось бы на моем примере понять и увидеть как можно решить задачу, и первым, и вторым способами.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[мне помогля статья в своё время:](http://nano.sapegin.ru/all/deploy)

Простой деплой сайта на хостинг из Git-репозитория

Давным-давно я заливал сайты в интернет с помощью FTP-клиента. Потом интернет стал быстрее и я стал прямо по FTP править странички, потому что каждый раз вручную копировать файлы было жутко неудобно.

Сейчас код всех моих сайтов находится в гит-репозиториях на Гитхабе или Битбакете, поэтому можно легко организовать выкладку сайтов оттуда: внесли изменения, закоммитили код, набрали команду в консоли, и через минуту пользователи уже видят новую версию сайта.

Для этого я использую свой шелл-скрипт [shipit](https://github.com/sapegin/shipit): он позволяет выполнять любые команды на сервере по SSH. До этого я долго использовал [Fabric](http://fabfile.org/), но Шипит проще и удобнее.

### Настройка авторизации

Для начала нужно настроить авторизацию с помощью SSH-ключей: без паролей и смс.

#### Создание SSH-ключа и добавление его на Гитхаб или Битбакет

Создание и использование ключей хорошо описано в документации [Гитхаба](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys) и [Битбакета](https://confluence.atlassian.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=270827678). Это нужно сделать и на локальном компьютере, и на хостинге, чтобы он тоже мог ходить на Гитхаб или Битбакет.

#### Создание псевдонима соединения

Чтобы не набирать каждый раз имя хоста и логин, можно создать псевдоним. Для этого добавим в файл `~/.ssh/config`:

Host myhost
    HostName 113.113.13.13
    User tema
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa

Замените данные на ваш хост, логин и ключ, созданный в предыдущем шаге.

#### Загрузка SSH-ключа на хостинг

Избавимся от необходимости вводить пароль при каждом заходе:

$ ssh myhost 'mkdir -p .ssh && cat >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

Теперь вы можете заходить на хостинг набирая:

$ ssh myhost

### Подготовка проекта

Для сборки я использую Грант. Если вы не используете Грант, можете пропустить этот раздел.

Есть два способа соборки и деплоя сайта:

1. Коммитить собранные файлы, деплоить простым `git pull`.
2. Коммитить только исходный код, собирать при деплое.

Я обычно использую второй. Репозиторий получается аккуратнее, диффы чище, работать удобнее. Но приходится настраивать на севере сборку. Однако с Грантом это не проблема.

Для деплоя я создаю специальную задачу `deploy`, где нет оптимизации картинок, тестирования и других долгих задач, не имеющих значения при сборке сайта.

grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint', 'concat', 'stylus', 'imagemin']);
grunt.registerTask('deploy', ['concat', 'stylus']);

Плагины для Гранта я всегда устанавливаю с ключом `--save-dev`, чтобы сохранять ссылки на их конкретные версии в `package.json`. Он должен выглядеть примерно так:

{
  "name": "example",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.2",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~0.2.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "~0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-stylus": "~0.11.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.4.0"
  }
}

Так я могу быть уверен, что сборка не сломается из-за того, что на сервере будет стоять неправильная версия какого-то пакета.

### Подготовка репозитория

Добавим в локальный репозиторий ссылку на удалённый (на Гитхабе или Битбакете) и запушим код:

$ git remote add origin git@github.com:sapegin/example.git
$ git push -u origin master

### Клонирование репозитория на хостинг

Клонируем репозиторий сайта на хостинг:

$ ssh myhost
$ git clone git@github.com:sapegin/example.git ~/sites/example.com
$ logout

Никаких паролей запрашиваться уже не должно.

### Установка shipit

Шипит устанавливается одной строкой:

```
$ path=/usr/local/bin/shipit; curl -o https://raw.github.com/sapegin/shipit/master/bin/shipit; chmod +x
```

### Настройка деплоя

Типичный скрипт деплоя у меня выглядит так:

```
git checkout master
git pull
npm install
node -e
```

Переведу на русский язык:

1. Переходим в ветку `master` (на всякий случай).
2. Получаем свежий код с Гитхаба/Битбакета.
3. Устанавливаем/обновляем npm-пакеты.
4. Запускам сборку Грантом.

Последний пункт нужно пояснить: я запускаю задачу `deploy` локально установленным (`npm install` без ключа `-g`) Грантом. Так всё нужное для деплоя (кроме Гита и npm) устанавливается одной командой `npm install` и не требует `sudo`.

Напишем скрипт для Шипита:

```
[deploy]
git checkout master
git pull
npm install
node -e <span class="string">"require('grunt').cli()"</span> _ deploy
```

И сохраним его как `.shipit` в папке проекта.

Шипит работает очень просто: он подключается к серверу по SSH, переходит в папку сайта и выполняет там команды, указанные после метки `[deploy]`. (На самом деле [возможностей](https://github.com/sapegin/shipit/blob/master/Readme.md) у него больше.)

Всё, теперь можно разложить сайт одной командой, не считая коммита и пуша изменений:

```
$ git commit -a -m <span class="string">"Make ponies pink."</span>
$ git push
$ shipit
```

Answer (score 1):

Для решения описаной вами рутинной задачи по обновлению версий файлов на тестовом или боевом сайтах сервисы типа Github добавили возможность создания [WebHook](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/), который будет стучаться на указанный адрес или скрипт при выбранных вами событиях, например при push в ветку develop или master будет вызываться обычный php файл(ну или в зависимости от того какой ЯП вы будете использовать) где будет прописано исполнение shell скрипта с необходимыми вами данными. Для примера советую посмотреть давнюю [статейку](http://rmcreative.ru/blog/post/prostoy-avtomaticheskiy-deploy-iz-repozitorija-github) которую гугл выдает практически сразу на подобный запрос. В комментариях к той статье кстати есть ссылка на более простой вариант [скрипта](https://github.com/h4/pullto/blob/master/pullto.sh). Так что ничего сложного в настройке автодеплоя по событиям репозитория нет, стоит только поискать.

Comment: continuous integration - вариант лучше

Answer (score -1):

Мне кажется что [вот эта статья на Хабре](https://habrahabr.ru/post/151997/) вам поможет.

Если кратко, то на сервере можно настроить хук post-receive, в котором запускать скрипт на обновление локальной копии тестового сервера из этого же репозитория.

Вроде бы в последних версиях git'а добавили возможность напрямую пушить в non-bare репозитории, но подробностей не помню.